# How to setup embedded Linux private vlan

Tags: linux-networking, vlan, embedded-linux

I am trying to setup a vlan between 2 embedded Linux SOCs on wireless IPTV STB (set top box) using vconfig. The physical connection between the SOCs is a Marvell 88E60xx switch. The issue is that the vlan needs to be private. If there is more than 1 IPTV STB, an RPC (remote procedure call) gets a response from the wrong STB and the static IP addresses I use are duplicated on the network. I see this on Wireshark.

> Duplicate IP address detected for 1.1.1.1 (28:c8:7a:b5:ad:50) - also
>   in use by 28:c8:7a:b5:ad:10 (frame 171)

I suspect I am missing 1 or 2 configuration steps but this is my 1st attempt at setting up a vlan. This is how I configure the vlan on the SOC that controls the WiFi

```
vconfig add br0 12
ip link set br0.12 up
ifconfig br0.12 1.1.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.248
```

This is how I configure the vlan on the SOC that controls the IPTV

```
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 multicast up
vconfig add eth0 0
ifconfig eth0.0 0.0.0.0 multicast up
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0.0
brctl addbr br6
brctl stp br6 0 # spanning tree protocol off
brctl setfd br6 0 # set bridge forward delay to 0 seconds
vconfig add eth0 12
ifconfig eth0.12 0.0.0.0 multicast up
brctl addif br6 eth0.12
ifconfig br6 1.1.1.1 up
```

This is the ifconfig on the SOC that controls the WiFi

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:C8:7A:B5:AD:11
          inet addr:192.168.1.230  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: /64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10266 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:130 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1032197 (1008.0 KiB)  TX bytes:10459 (10.2 KiB)

br0.12    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:C8:7A:B5:AD:11
          inet addr:1.1.1.2  Bcast:1.1.1.7  Mask:255.255.255.248
          inet6 addr: /64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:11585 (11.3 KiB)  TX bytes:9991 (9.7 KiB)

eth1_0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:C8:7A:B5:AD:13
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9910 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:47291704 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:512
          RX bytes:927138 (905.4 KiB)  TX bytes:1386129256 (1.2 GiB)
          Interrupt:20

wifi0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:C8:7A:B5:AD:11
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:47372174 errors:26 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19386 errors:4 dropped:4 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1536
          RX bytes:2526373464 (2.3 GiB)  TX bytes:1626473 (1.5 MiB)
```

This is the ifconfig on the SOC that controls the IPTV

```
br6       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:C8:7A:B5:AD:10
          inet addr:1.1.1.1  Bcast:1.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:87 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:5801 (5.6 KiB)  TX bytes:8981 (8.7 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:C8:7A:B5:AD:10
          inet addr:10.70.246.245  Bcast:10.70.246.255  Mask:255.255.255.240
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:46704864 errors:140 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:226
          TX packets:19531 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:128
          RX bytes:433498829 (413.4 MiB)  TX bytes:821667 (802.4 KiB)
          Interrupt:46

eth0.0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:C8:7A:B5:AD:10
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0.12   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 28:C8:7A:B5:AD:10
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:87 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:6149 (6.0 KiB)  TX bytes:9461 (9.2 KiB)
```

This is a cat /proc/net/vlan/* on the SOC that controls the WiFi

```
br0.12  VID: 12  REORDER_HDR: 1  dev->priv_flags: 1
         total frames received          266
          total bytes received        16535
      Broadcast/Multicast Rcvd            0

      total frames transmitted          191
       total bytes transmitted        20024
            total headroom inc            0
           total encap on xmit          191
Device: br0
INGRESS priority mappings: 0:0  1:0  2:0  3:0  4:0  5:0  6:0 7:0
 EGRESS priority mappings:
VLAN Dev name    | VLAN ID
Name-Type: VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD
br0.12         | 12  | br0
```

This is a cat /proc/net/vlan/* on the SOC that controls the IPTV

```
VLAN Dev name    | VLAN ID
Name-Type: VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD
eth0.0         | 0  | eth0
eth0.12        | 12  | eth0
eth0.0  VID: 0   REORDER_HDR: 1  dev->priv_flags: 1
         total frames received            0
          total bytes received            0
      Broadcast/Multicast Rcvd            0

      total frames transmitted            0
       total bytes transmitted            0
            total headroom inc            0
           total encap on xmit            0
Device: eth0
INGRESS priority mappings: 0:0  1:0  2:0  3:0  4:0  5:0  6:0 7:0
EGRESSS priority Mappings:
eth0.12  VID: 12         REORDER_HDR: 1  dev->priv_flags: 1
         total frames received          183
          total bytes received        17613
      Broadcast/Multicast Rcvd            6

      total frames transmitted          252
       total bytes transmitted        18699
            total headroom inc           39
           total encap on xmit          252
Device: eth0
INGRESS priority mappings: 0:0  1:0  2:0  3:0  4:0  5:0  6:0 7:0
EGRESSS priority Mappings:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to isolate the vlan by turning off arp like this

```
ifconfig br6 -arp #turn off arp
```

and setting arp like this

```
arp -s 1.1.1.2 $WMAC
```

and doing something similar on the other side of the bridge like this

```
ifconfig br0 -arp #turn off arp
ifconfig br0.12 -arp #turn off arp
```

and

```
arp -s 1.1.1.1 $EMAC
```